# Passing optional events to a method that has default parameters

Tags: python, tkinter, parameters

I have a method that takes optional events. Sometimes it will be called by a widget command thus no event and sometimes by a key press bound to the Tkinter window which passes an event. However, when the method is called via the keypress the boolean value passed with the lambda function is not getting passed - the method always prints a True value (its default parameter). What am I doing wrong? Here is workable example.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Call Method", command=self.meth)
        self.button.pack()
        self.bind("<Control-s>", lambda var = False : self.meth(var))

    def meth(self, *event, var=True):
        print(event, var)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Main()
    main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why not just use another method so it doesn't require a variable

Comment: If I can't figure out how to do it this way then I will have to.

Comment: I'm pretty unfamiliar with tkinter but trying to help, does it send anything different as `event`?

Comment: Yes just figured that out. Dumb mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Lol, cheers! Glad you got it :D

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured this out. Rookie mistake. The key press should have been bound to a `lambda event` like this:

```
self.bind("<Control-s>", lambda event, var = False : self.meth(var))
```